# Stop UIPickerViewAnimation

Tags: xcode, animation, uidatepicker

Is there a way to instantly stop the animation of rolling UIPIckerView or UIDatePicker on button click.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`

Since Picker can only show limited number of results at a time. You can implement an algorithm to determine what is in the middle of the result when this method is called. It gets called every time a new option appears (just like tableView viewForIndexPath). So scrolling up or down will call this method.

Beware, you would need to add padding options to first few choices and last few choices just so that it works correctly. This will get you the effect you want. Be warned, Apple might not agree with this method as it doesnt act like what Apple intended picker to do.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [`UIPickerView` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW11), you'll see:

> **selectRow:inComponent:animated:**
>
> Selects a row in a specified component
>   of the picker view.
>
> ```
> - (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row 
>       inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
>          animated:(BOOL)animated
> ```

You could call this method when your button is pushed, sending `NO` for the animated parameter, to instantly select a particular row.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that. I mean stop animation at row that selected at the moment when I press the button. Or al least get current value of the picker. For example, UIDatePicker date property changes only when animation stops. But I do know that it's possible to get instant value cause I saw it in another app. :) I hope it's clear what I mean. English is not my native language.